# jsonpath buffer to string

Tags: json, jsonpath

I read snmp from a printer with node-red, and pass it via mqtt to an mqtt-app which uses jsonPath to parse the json.

The json is

```
[{"oid":"1.3.6.1.2.1.43.18.1.1.8.1.1",
 "value":
    {"type":"Buffer",
     "data":[48,49,48,45,52,50,49,58,82,101,112,108,97, 
             99,101,32,70,117,115,101,114,32,115,111,111,110,46]}}
,{"oid":.....
```

By using the this expression

```
$[0].value.data
```

I get displayed

```
[48,49,48,45,52,50,49,58,82,101,112,108,97,
```

This data is ascii, how do I get this displayed as characters?

Comment: So you would like to transform the array `[48,49,48,45,52,50,49...` to a corresponding string just by using a single jsonPath expression, that you'd enter in a mqtt app?

Comment: Yes, that's right.